# Splitting a comma separated string and discarding some values in the string

Tags: java, regex, string

Given the following string:

```
423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]
```

I would like to split it and put the contents in a array excluding the square brackets and the numbers in the brackets - i.e the result should be an array that contains the following.

```
{423545,7568787,53654656,2021947,021947,2021947,8021947}
```

My attempt so far only works if there are no square brackets:

```
String str = "342398789, [233434],423545(50),[7568787(500)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(150),[8021947(50)]";
String[] listItems = str.split("(\\(\\d+\\))?(?:,|$)")
```

How can I update the above regex to also extract the numbers that wrapped in square brackets?

The strings I am trying to extract are identifiers for database rows so i need to extract them to retrieve the database row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this way

```
String str = "[342398789], [233434] ,423545(50),[7568787(500)],"
        + "53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(150),[8021947(50)]";
String[] listItems = str.replaceFirst("^\\[", "").split(
        "(\\(\\d+\\))?\\]?(\\s*,\\s*\\[?|$)");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listItems));
```

output

> [342398789, 233434, 423545, 7568787, 53654656, 2021947, 021947, 2021947, 8021947]

Comment: Thanks. This almost works but ignores the first square bracket for this string "[423545(50)],7568787(50),[53654656],2021947(50)"

Comment: @ziggy Could you check updated version? I decided to remove `[` from beginning to avoid empty String at start after split.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon in the middle of the expression?

Comment: @ziggy My bad, copy-paste mistake, now it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
String str = "342398789, [233434],423545(50),[7568787(500)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(150),[8021947(50)]";
String[] listItems = str.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)","")replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","").split(",");
```

Comment: You forgot to add \\ before `d+` in first replacement, and `.` before second replaceAll method. Btw. you can use "or" in regex ( `|` ) and use replaceAll only one :)